# Pentaho bi server and administration-console communications

Tags: pentaho

I was deploy pentaho bi server on my running tomcat server ref from [here](http://iamraghavan.blogspot.in/2011/12/installing-pentaho-bi-on-tomcatjboss.html).
Now I want to create JNDI bases datasource so I login through pentaho administration console but in that web page nothing to shows users lists, user role. After googling some times I was found that change console.xml then I was changed my console.xml file as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<console> 
<solution-path>/home/pc-name/pentaho-solutions</solution-path>
<war-path>/home/pc-name/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/pentaho</war-path>
<platform-username>joe</platform-username>  
<biserver-status-check-period-millis>30000</biserver-status-check-period-millis>  
<homepage-url>http://www.pentaho.com/console_home</homepage-url>  
<homepage-timeout-millis>15000</homepage-timeout-millis>  
<!-- comma separated list of roles (no spaces) -->  
<default-roles>Authenticated</default-roles>
<default-server-dir>biserver-ce</default-server-dir>
</console>
```

then I was stopped administration console and then again start but still it not shows me any user lists, role lists. After that I hard coded start-pac.sh as below

```
DIR_REL=`dirname $0`
cd $DIR_REL
DIR=`/home/pc-name/apache-tomcat-7.0.47`
cd -

. "$DIR/set-pentaho-env.sh"

setPentahoEnv "$DIR/../biserver-ce/jre"
```

but running at start-pac.sh it shows set-pentaho-env.sh not found but in my first steps deploying pentaho bi server on existing tomcat it not mentioned anything about set-pentaho-env.sh where to copy or set. Can any one knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Pentaho 5.0 doesn't have an admin console because both user roles and database connections are easily configured in the user console. It seems you just started to deploy your biserver so I suggest you upgrade to the new version and leave admin console behind. Trust me. You will like it.

Long answer: If you still wish to stay with 4.8 for some strange reason:
Don't change anything in Pac-start.bat, revert to the original version before your changes. If you need to change the default URL or port, then
find biserver-ce\tomcat\conf\server.xml
the default for pentaho user console is 8080, and the default admin console port is 8443. Change those to your preference. Once done,
find biserver-ce\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\WEB-INF\web.xml

change here:

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>fully-qualified-server-url</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080/pentaho/</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

then find the list of trusted Ip's and add additional trusted IP's here (this is somewhere around line 133)

```
   <param-name>TrustedIpAddrs</param-name>
   <param-value>127.0.0.1,0\:0\:0\:0\:0\:0\:0\:1(%.+)*$</param-value>
   <description>Comma separated list of IP addresses of a trusted hosts.</description>
```

(Also covered in this article: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/Setting+up+trust+between+Administration+Console+and+BI+Server)

Make sure when you start the admin console, pentaho biserver is running already. Admin console will not work if the biserver is not running.
Make sure you use the correct JDK, because a wrong java configuration, or wrong java_home_path can also cause admin console to not stand up.

Really, just go with Pentaho 5.0.1.

Comment: thx for replay now I go through pentaho CE 5.0 and found my solution.