# How to Configure the Pentaho Administration Console?

Tags: tomcat, pentaho

After integration of BI server  with ms-sql server,I want to configure **administration-console**.

I have followed following link(of **prashantraju**) for configuration of
*Windows and Microsoft SQL Server*

https://docs.google.com/document/d/11bJ4dGw2vhVj8fif872fxut7BrLg4UYiD3s4zyFEaXY/edit?authkey=CN3-z9kK&pli=1

From administrative console I am able to add new role and user.it is successfully added into databse.but when i login with that users,**A login error occurred.**
Login is possible with default **username** joe and **password** : password.
i am not able to recognize how it is possible.let me know the solution.

having errors on BI server console like
[image]

Comment: How can you assert the new user is database? Did you look up in Hibernate db?

Comment: @andtorg I am using administration-console front end to create new user.Now the problem is solved.

Comment: @andtorg Do you have any idea how to create window service for administrative console like we create window service for BI-Server.

Comment: bajrangi use a tool called svrany to do that - lets you convert any java process to a proper windows service. there's a guide on the pentaho wiki about how to do it for carte.  Although thats not really related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the new users. Note than in Pentaho 5 there is no administration console. All features can be accessed from the user console. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122337/pentaho-bi-server-and-administration-console-communications)

P.S. The predefined user for Pentaho 5.0 is Suzy with password "password".